# Onclick Function when input field requirements are met

Tags: javascript, html, forms, buttonclick

I want the submit button's to call the function only if the input fields meet the requirements set. Is there an easier way to do it than making an if statement for each input element?

```
<div class="container">
            <form>
                <input id="inputname" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Your Name">
                <input id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" type="email" name="email" required>
                <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="123-456-7890" required>
                <textarea type="text" rows="4" placeholder="Add comments(optional)" id="comments"></textarea>
                <button type="submit" onclick="submitted()"> Reserve a Table</button>
            </form>
</div>
    

<script>
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
function submitted() {
        container.innerHTML = `<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-check"></i><br>
        Thank you, the form has been submitted!`
  }
</script>
```

Comment: But each input has different requirement needs? 
Then you really can't do anything else than validate them all separately.
Also, you have not shown how you do validation right now so it's difficult to say how to do it in more eloquent way.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The `submitted` function is only called when HTML 5 validation passes when I test it.

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** See [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) for more details on form validation.

In particular, under the header [Using built-in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation):

> When an element is invalid, the following things are true:
> ...
> If the user tries to send the data, the browser will block the form and display an error message.

See also the note under the [constraint validation process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation#constraint_validation_process) to learn more about when this happens.

The originally posted sample is shown [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyvtckzo/) but lacked a dot at the start of the `container` selector.

As a solution here, you can move the function call to the onsubmit handler of the form, instead of the click handler of the submit button.  That fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly7aq8ge/) and includes just the following changed tags: `<form onsubmit="submitted()">` and `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: I am using VSCode and the live server extension. When I click the submit button it automatically changes the inner html. I just realized the reason it works on jfiddle is becasue I didn't add the period when declaring the container constant. It should be ('.container") when I do that it will automatically change the HTML even when the requirements aren't met. I have changed the code in the question to fix that problem.

Comment: @MessyMonkey Answer updated to reflect the changed question.

Comment: Thank you the onsubmit added to the form fixed my problem!